# Angular: Array sorting

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to use the function below to create a list of array that is sorted by unique careOfferingName. So for example with the json below it create the array so that it contains

```
Before School

After School

BeforeAAA School

AfterAAA School
```

So basicalaly i am trying to sort this.careOfferingspaceList to only have the indexs that have unique careOfferingNames

.ts

```
  getCareOfferingName(careOffering: CareOfferingSpace[]){
    var test = this.careOfferingSpaceList.filter(val=>{
     return val.careOfferingName == careOfferingName;
    })  ; 

    return test;
  }
```

json:

```
 "careOffering": [
         {
            "id": 3,
            "careOptionId": 1713,
            "schoolId": 422,
            "schoolName": "ABC Learning",
            "careOfferingName": "Before School",
            "spaceAvailable": null,
            "careOfferingSpaceAvailableId": 3
          }, {
            "id": 3,
            "careOptionId": 1713,
            "schoolId": 422,
            "schoolName": "ABC Learning",
            "careOfferingName": "After School",
            "spaceAvailable": null,
            "careOfferingSpaceAvailableId": 3
         }, 
          {
            "id": 4,
            "careOptionId": 1713,
            "schoolId": 422,
            "schoolName": "Ha",
            "careOfferingName": "Before School",
            "spaceAvailable": null,
            "careOfferingSpaceAvailableId": 3
          }, {
            "id": 4,
            "careOptionId": 1713,
            "schoolId": 422,
            "schoolName": "Ha",
            "careOfferingName": "After School",
            "spaceAvailable": null,
            "careOfferingSpaceAvailableId": 3
         },
          {
            "id": 4,
            "careOptionId": 1713,
            "schoolId": 422,
            "schoolName": "Ha",
            "careOfferingName": "BeforeAAA School",
            "spaceAvailable": null,
            "careOfferingSpaceAvailableId": 3
          }, {
            "id": 4,
            "careOptionId": 1713,
            "schoolId": 422,
            "schoolName": "Ha",
            "careOfferingName": "AfterAAA School",
            "spaceAvailable": null,
            "careOfferingSpaceAvailableId": 3
         },
      ]
```

This is the object that careofferingspacelist array is built from
careOfferingSpace.ts

```
export class CareOfferingSpace {
    public id: number;
    public careOptionId: number;
    public weekNo: string;
    public startDate: string;
    public endDate: string;
    public spaceAvailable: string;
    public careOfferingSpaceAvailableId: number;
    public schoolId: number;
    public schoolName: string;
    public careOfferingName: string;
  }
```

Comment: What is `getCareOfferingName ` doing? And which variable do you want to sort? What have you tried?

Comment: trying to sort this.careOfferingSpaceList ... and getOFferingName is supposed to sort this.careOfferingSpaceList and return only the indexs with unique careOfferingName

Comment: Where is `careOfferingSpaceList `? Also what is the expected output?

Comment: updated the post with careoffierng space list object and the output is supposed to be the array with only unique care offering names.. for example you see "Before School" exists twice in the array. it should only return back once when filtered

Comment: Okay and what exactly is the logic behind your sorting?

Comment: hey @BadGuyKUTA IS ans is working ? If yes than accept it for reference of new user who are visiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this function ,

```
function myFunction() {
     var obj = {}; 
     return this.careOffering.filter(function (item) {
     return obj.hasOwnProperty(item.careOfferingName) ? false : (obj[item.careOfferingName] = true)
     })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getCareOfferingName(careOffering: CareOfferingSpace[]) {
  // Will return array of careOfferingName
  var test = this.careOfferingSpaceList.map(val => val.careOfferingName);
  // Get unique values
  test =
    let unique = [...new Set(test)];
  // Sort the array now
  test = test.sort((a, b) => a > b); // I dont know the exact sorting logic you would require, you can modify it accordingly
  // return the array
  return test;
}
```